# Deploying a spring roo, hibernated java web project to jboss 4.2.3 fails due to no declaration of mvc:default-servlet-handler

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, deployment, jboss

I'm deploying a java web site that uses spring roo and hibernate to JBoss 4.2.3. It consistently fails due to the certain tags not being declared:

```
<mvc:resources>
<mvc:default-servlet-handler>
```

The bean def for the webmvc-config.xml schema is as follows:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    
xmlns:util="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">
```

the spring jar versions we are using are 3.0.5. I'm positive those tags are available post 3.0.4.  We are using maven to manage our dependencies yet no matter how much I do a clean install, it fails to deploy.  I'm at a loss here.  I've also tried removing the -3.0 from the xsds in the schema but to no avail.

I have no idea what is missing.

Thanks~!

Answer (score 1):

The problem was a mixed dependency in my project.  For some reason our project was using springbyexample and this dependency was causing the project to pull down older versions of the jars I needed in order to get the project to deploy properly.  This caused JBoss to be deem that the tags were unsupported.